# Problem with NextJs v13 generateMetadata()

Tags: next.js, vercel

Everything works well on the localhost, I can fetch data inside the generateMetadata function, and it shows the title and everything.

When I try to run it on the server it says: Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

I can see that is a problem with the data I'm fetching, because when I use static data I don't have any problem with it.

This is my function on the page.js file:

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {

  const collection = await WooCommerce.get(`products/categories/${params.id}`)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    return {
      title: `${collection.name} | Flores El Gato`,
    };
}
```

This is the error I get on the Log:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at Module.generateMetadata (/var/task/.next/server/app/collection/[id]/page.js:1221:20)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
digest: '132657019'
}

Answer (score 1):

The property `collection` is undefined. That is why you get this error, try the following code snippet, this will insert a default title when the collection is undefined.

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const { data: collection } = await WooCommerce.get(
    `products/categories/${params.id}`,
  );

  return {
    title: `${collection?.name ?? "Default title"} | Flores El Gato`,
  };
}
```

As you see, in this example I use the [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator in conjunction with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent a crash due to undefined values.